# Can we apply the REP, CRP, CCP, etc. principles to Java packages as well as to JARs?

Tags: java, oop, package, package-design

Uncle Bob's Principles of OOD (http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod) describes:

- The five principles of class design
- The six principles of package design (The Release Reuse Equivalency Principle, The Common Closure Principle, etc.)

The article states that:

> In this context a package is a binary deliverable like a .jar file, or a dll as opposed to a namespace like a Java package or a C++ namespace.

Does it mean that the 6 "package principles" are **not** applicable to Java packages (which are defined with the keyword *package*) at all? Does that mean it would be a mistake to apply them in this manner? If so, could you point out to where such namespace-package principles can be found?

Comment: It's telling you that the term `package` as used in the document has *nothing* to do with java packages (in terms of the keyword). As for the second bullet-point; I don't actually know what you're asking. The [Wikipedia entry for Namespace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace) explains it in a non-programming context. There's a bunch of good practices out there, but there are no *principles* of namespaces per se.

Comment: The issue is that there is another article (http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/granularity.pdf) which describes exactly same six packaging principles. But it says: in this article we will ...refer to these higher order granules as “packages”. ...The term “package” is common in Ada and Java circles. In those languages a package is used to represent a logical grouping of declarations that can be imported into other programs. So the question is: **can we apply REP, CRP, CCP ... principles to java NS packages as well as to java archives (JARs)**? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the package principles can be applied to single Java packages, or equivalent groupings of classes (or other single units of software) in other languages.

[The first article in Martin's series of articles about package principles, that about the Release Reuse Equivalency Principle](http://docs.google.com/a/cleancoder.com/viewer?a=v&pid=explorer&chrome=true&srcid=0BwhCYaYDn8EgOGM2ZGFhNmYtNmE4ZS00OGY5LWFkZTYtMjE0ZGNjODQ0MjEx&hl=en), explains that the principles are about groupings of classes. It rather arbitrarily chooses "package" as a name for those groupings, then mentions that that word is used in Ada and Java for specific types of groupings in those languages. I conclude that the principles apply to *any* grouping of classes, Java packages included.

Others have successfully applied the package principles to Java packages. [JDepend](http://clarkware.com/software/JDepend.html) calculates metrics based on the package principles for Java packages. I still miss the wonderful tool [Optimal Advisor](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiSwIykyvvKAhUM8GMKHaNoDQ0QFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsupportline.microfocus.com%2FDocumentation%2Fbooks%2FDevPartner%2Fdoc%2FDPJ%2FDPJ44%2FPDF%2FOptimalAdvisor.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGgb-Ze2oK61LM8nLSLtBsFY3KFsw&sig2=kTmHU4dACOoSd6C_BDtJow), which displayed those metrics on a package dependency graph as an aid to refactoring. I found both of them useful in identifying packages which violated the package principles and confirming when I'd fixed those violations by refactoring, such as moving classes to the appropriate packages.